# Plotting with GNU Plot, title based on column name

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file composed of 3 columns, which format is: X Axis Value | Title ID | Y axis Value

I don´t know how to plot it using columns 1:3 and 2 for the title name. Here is an example:

```
X Axis  Plot  Y Axis
2000    plot1 1.2
2000    plot2 4.6
2000    plot3 5.7
3000    plot1 5.8
3000    plot2 7.5
3000    plot3 8.3
```

So here, we will have 3 plots which should have second column values on their names (1, 2 and 3); 2000 and 3000 would be the X axis values and the thrid column represents de Y value.

So, the "title-2" graph would be: (2000, 4.6) and (3000, 7.5)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62498110/7295599 it's pretty similar. If you have difficulties to adapt it to your needs, modify your question and describe the exact problem.

Comment: Yes, it is very similar! But I don´t get the way to adapt it. I have modified the data to display. There would be 3 plots, named plot1, plot2 and plot3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a UNIX user or the "grep" command is callable from gnuplot, you may consider the following approach.

```
set xrange [1000:4000]
set yrange [0:10]

plot for [i=1:3] \
        sprintf("< grep plot%i test.dat",i) using 1:3 with linespoints title sprintf("plot%i", i)
```

The above plot command is a bit more complicated because of the use of "for loop" and "sprintf", but is equivalent to the following.

```
plot "< grep plot1 test.dat" using 1:3 with linespoints title "plot1", \
     "< grep plot2 test.dat" using 1:3 with linespoints title "plot2", \
     "< grep plot3 test.dat" using 1:3 with linespoints title "plot3"
```

Answer (score 0):

The adapted "gnuplot only" version for your case might look like this.
`fcol` is the filter column number, `myKey` your keyword, and `dcol` the data column number. It's not clear to me whether you want 3 lines in 1 graph, or 3 lines in 3 graphs on 1 canvas (`multiplot`, like example below), or the graph in 1 file on disk or maybe distributed on 3 files on disk.

**Code:**

```
### split data by keyword for each plot
reset session

$Data <<EOD
X Axis  Plot    Y Axis
2000    plot1   1.2
2000    plot2   4.6
2000    plot3   5.7
3000    plot1   5.8
3000    plot2   7.5
3000    plot3   8.3
EOD

myFilter(fcol,myKey,dcol) = strcol(fcol) eq myKey ? column(dcol) : NaN
set datafile missing NaN
set key top left

set multiplot layout 3,1
    do for [i=1:3] {
        myKey = sprintf("plot%d",i)
        set title myKey
        plot $Data u 1:(myFilter(2,myKey,3)) w lp pt 7 lc i title myKey
    }
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (all lines in one plot)

If you have regular file pattern in your rows, e.g. `1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,...` or `1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,...` you possibly could also work with `every`, check `help every`.
However, this filtering with the ternary operator should work for all cases, including random `1,3,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,...` sequences.

**Code:**

```
### split data by keyword
reset session

$Data <<EOD
X Axis  Plot    Y Axis
2000    plot1   1.2
2000    plot2   4.6
2000    plot3   5.7
3000    plot1   5.8
3000    plot2   7.5
3000    plot3   8.3
EOD

myFilter(fcol,myKey,dcol) = strcol(fcol) eq myKey ? column(dcol) : NaN
set datafile missing NaN
set key top left

myKey(i) = sprintf("plot%d",i)
set title "Plot 1,2,3"
plot for [i=1:3] $Data u 1:(myFilter(2,myKey(i),3)) w lp pt 7 lc i title myKey(i)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: But, is there a way to have this three plots in the same graphic?

Comment: yes, of course! I will add it to the answer.